# How to automate dictionary creation in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a python code that solves a Sudoku puzzle. My code starts by making a list of each row/column combination, or the coordinates of each box. Next, I want to find a way to, for each box, reference its location.
This is my current code:

```
boxes = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    for x in range(1,10):
        boxes = boxes + ['r'+str(i)+'c'+str(x)]
for box in boxes:
```

Next, I was going to create a dictionary for each one, but I would want each to be named by the list item. The dictionaries would be, for example, r1c1 = {'row': '1', 'Column': 1}.

What is the best way to separate and store this information?

Comment: There's definitely a better solution. What's the point of creating those dictionaries?

Comment: `boxes = boxes + ['r'+str(i)+'c'+str(x)]` is a somewhat expensive way of spelling `boxes.append('r'+str(i)+'c'+str(x))` or even `boxes.append('r{}c{}'.fromat(i, c))`.

Comment: There is *no point* in creating that many dictionaries. You'd be much better off just storing `(i, c)` (a tuple) in your list. That way you don't have to map back to the row, column format *at all*, you'd already have the coordinates. Don't use strings as intermediaries.

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to python and am still learning how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create all those dictionaries. You already have your coordinates, just don't lock them up in strings:

```
boxes = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    for x in range(1,10):
        boxes.append((i, x))
```

would create a list of `(row, column)` tuples instead, and you then wouldn't have to map them back.

Even if you needed to associate strings with data, you could do so in a *nested* dictionary:

```
coordinates = {
    'r1c1': {'row': 1, 'column': 1},
    # ...
}
```

but you could also parse that string and extract the numbers after `r` and `c` to produce the row and column numbers again.

In fact, I wrote a Sudoku checker on the same principles once; in the following code `block_indices`, `per9()` and `zip(*per9(s))` produce indices for each block, row or column of a puzzle, letting you verify that you have 9 unique values in each. The only difference is that instead of a matrix, I used *one long list* to represent a puzzle, all elements from row to row included in sequence:

```
from itertools import product

block_indices = [[x + y + s for s in (0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19, 20)]
                 for x, y in product(range(0, 81, 27), range(0, 9, 3))]

def per9(iterable):
    # group iterable in chunks of 9
    return zip(*([iter(iterable)] * 9))

def is_valid_sudoku(s):
    return (
        # rows
        all(len(set(r)) == 9 for r in per9(s)) and
        # columns
        all(len(set(c)) == 9 for c in zip(*per9(s))) and
        # blocks
        all(len(set(s[i] for i in ix)) == 9 for ix in block_indices)
    )
```

So row 1, column 4 is 1 * 9 + 4 = index 13 in a flat list.

Answer (score 0):

While Martijn's answer is probably better from a "what you should do" perspective, for completeness, you could build that structure pretty easily using [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

The below annotated code will output your desire data structure:

```
boxes = {
    "r%sc%s"%(i,j):         # build the keys in the form "r1c2" 
      {'row':i,"column":j}  # build the dictionary of values - {'row':1, 'column': 2}
    for i in range(1,10)    # first level of loop
    for j in range(1,10)    # second level of loop
}    
print boxes
```

This will output in your desired format:

```
{   'r1c1': {   'column': 1, 'row': 1},
    'r1c2': {   'column': 2, 'row': 1},
    'r1c3': {   'column': 3, 'row': 1},
    'r1c4': {   'column': 4, 'row': 1},
 ....
}
```